# Query about optical data extraction using Vaspkit

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, optical-properties, vaspkit, dielectric-constants

Recently I tried to extract the optical absorption data using Vaspkit (vaspkit.1.3.0/vaspkit.1.3.5]). I performed the optical calculations of one 2d system along with SOC using VASP. While extracting the data, I found that in the REAL.in and IMAG.in files (real and imaginary part of dielectric constant), the energy range from 0 to 23 eV, whereas in the ABSORPTION_2D.dat file, I am getting data in the energy range from 0 to 7 eV only.
I am not getting why this is happening because, as per my understanding, the absorption coefficient should come in the same range as the real and imaginary part is coming. In the absorption coefficient I am getting the data upto 7 eV only.
It would be very kind if anyone please suggest to me why this is happening, or this is the problem with Vaspkit for the 2d system.

Comment: Maybe you figured it out by now, but my guess is that the VASPKIT developers just chose to process the values between 0 to 7 eV. If I'm not mistaken, the formalism they used for 2D materials is in line with this paper (https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.205408). The post-processing steps are pretty minimal, so I'd recommend just post-processing the REAL.in and IMAG.in yourself (or if you have doubts, write a simple script to extract those values yourself, or double check with how pymatgen extracts those values).

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but did the comment by CW Tan help answer your question? Please update us!

Comment: In my calculations, I considered the energy up to 7 eV, and I didn't get the reason for it. What CW Tan is suggesting is that one can do it manually by writing a script; that is possible, but I didn't try. But Yes, this is also one way to get the result.